# Widevine video streaming on iOS and AirPlay

Tags: ios, iphone, video-streaming, drm, widevine

Could you help us please with the following problem related to the DRM (Widevine) encrypted video stream playback and use of the AirPlay?

When we tried to play the video from iPhone with use of the AirPlay on Apple TV, the "failed to load content” error was shown on the TV screen. We are not sure if that is correct behaviour. We think it is, because for encrypted video playback we cannot use the AirPlay as it transports the raw unencrypted stream, right?

So far we found that the only possible solution is showing video on iPhone, while playing audio on the AppleTV, it seems that for audio the DRM restriction does not apply.

Could you confirm the above description? Could you give us some advices?

We found also following (Note that we are not using Brightcove, but the principle should be same) information on the Internet: http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/widevine-plugin-brightcove-video-cloud-player-sdk-ios

Comment: Hi, I already found solution. There was a new library released (6.0.0.12578) and it includes AirPlay support.

Comment: Do you have any tutorials on how to use widevine on iOS?pls help,i am stuck.

Comment: The Brightcove link is dead. And a better answer would be nice - same boat here.

Answer (score 2):

Try `WVUseEncryptedLoopback` (set it to `@1`). It enables AirPlay support by securing the AirPlay stream. 1 enables encrypted loopback. 0 by default.

Also, enable `WVPlayerDrivenAdaptationKey` (set it to `@1`) (Switch between Apple Native Player Adaption = 1 and Widevine Adaption = 0)

Widevine version: 6.0.0.12792