# Playing Widevine DRM on iOS?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, exoplayer, widevine

I'm hoping to find something similar to ExoPlayer for iOS.

The goal is to play/stream Widevine DRM protected videos on iOS. I have all I need server side, but I can't find a suitable player.

Does anyone have suggestions for me about open source, free, paid players?

Comment: I've seen some references to a Widevine SDK for iOS but I can't find any docs. How did you manage to find the server side documentation, are you a CWIP?

Comment: My content provider are. 

Refrences to the Widevine on iOS on Stack:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721420/widevine-drm-playback-sample-code-parameter-values-ios
 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781882/widevine-video-streaming-on-ios-and-airplay

Comment: hi frikish did you find any answer,i am also looking similar to exoplayer

Answer (score 2):

Google provides [Widevine CDM for iOS](https://storage.googleapis.com/wvdocs/Widevine_DRM_Getting_Started_CDM_for_iOS.pdf). It is not a whole player, you will need to integrate it to a player of your choice. It is also not directly available, you will have to sign license agreement with Google (NDA).